# Why there can be multiple Location fields in an HTTP response header?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, safari, http-headers, httpresponse

I see there may be multiple Location fields in an HTTP response header. My understanding is that it is used for redirection. But why there can be multiple redirection destinations.

Which one among mulitple Location fields will be used in practice for redirection (e.g., in Firefox, Chrome, Safari)? Is it always the first one?

```
$ wget -U 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36' -q -O /dev/null -S -o- --max-redirect 1 http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/ncb2867 | grep '^  Location: '
  Location: http://www.nature.com/articles/ncb2867
  Location: https://www.nature.com/articles/ncb2867
```

Answer (score 0):

You've specified `--max-redirects=1`, which means "follow the first redirect".

So you're simply seeing

- both the redirect target from the first response:

  ```
  $ curl -i http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/ncb2867 | grep Location
  Location: http://www.nature.com/articles/ncb2867
  ```
- as well as from the response to the second request to location returned in the first response:

  ```
  $ curl -i http://www.nature.com/articles/ncb2867
  Location: https://www.nature.com/articles/ncb2867
  ```

> Which one among multiple `Location` fields will be used in practice for redirection

You can easily test it by running `nc -l 8000`, loading http://localhost:8000 in the browser, then pasting the response you wish to test into the console. In Firefox response like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 OK
Content-Length: 0
Connection: Closed
Location: http://localhost:8000/foo
Location: http://localhost:8000/bar
```

results in "Corrupted Content Error" - "The site at http://localhost:8000/ has experienced a network protocol violation that cannot be repaired."